# AWS Cognito Saas Demo: How does it "Get Access Token (with IAM policies)?"

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

**Setup**
I am working through ["Saas identity and isolation with Amazon Cognito"](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/saas/identity-with-cognito/) deployment [guide](https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/saas-identity-cognito/doc/saas-identity-and-isolation-with-cognito-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf) and accompanying [source code](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/saas-identity-cognito).

After deploying, testing, and reading everything, I was able to figure out

- How to work with Cognito users/user pools per tenant
- How to create roles per tenant
- How to create tenant based policies
- How to create identity pools per tenant

**Main Question** 
How does it all tie together? Specifically, How does user in a tenant user pool get associated with a policy in an identity pool? There seems to be some hand waving around "Get Access Token (with IAM policies)". How does that work? How do the custom authorizers fit in?

**More information**
I believe that it has to do with [token-manager.js:346](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/saas-identity-cognito/blob/master/app/source/shared-modules/token-manager/token-manager.js#L346)

```
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity({apiVersion: '2014-06-30',region: configuration.aws_region});
var params = {
    IdentityId: event.IdentityId, /* required */
    //CustomRoleArn: 'STRING_VALUE',
    Logins: {
        [event.provider]: event.token,
        /* '<IdentityProviderName>': ... */
    }
};
cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity(params, function (err, data) {
```

I see that [getCredentialsForIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#getCredentialsForIdentity-property) is documented to take a CustomRoleArn, as per below. The code above has this commented out, but the code still works.

```
var params = {
  IdentityId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  CustomRoleArn: 'STRING_VALUE',
  Logins: {
    '<IdentityProviderName>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<IdentityProviderName>': ... */
  }
};
```

**Custom Authorizer**
The only code in the [custom-authorizer/index.js](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/saas-identity-cognito/blob/master/functions/source/custom-authorizer/index.js#L192), that I can find in relation to permission/policy is:

```
var policy = new AuthPolicy(principalId, awsAccountId, apiOptions);
policy.allowAllMethods();
const authResponse = policy.build();
```

<*Gasp*> This code makes it appear that we are bypassing all policies. Is it possible that this app is faking it and only handling routing in Angular? Probably not.

**Additional question**
I have been able to extract almost everything I need to know through [AWS PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/). The one thing I don't know how to retrieve is the User Pool Identity Provider. The [Get-CGIPIdentityProvider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/index.html?page=Get-CGIPIdentityProvider.html&tocid=Get-CGIPIdentityProvider) cmdlet requires a "ProviderName". What is this? "Cognito"? "www.amazon.com"? Some identifier?

Repeating **Main Question** in case you just scroll to the bottom. 
How does it all tie together? Specifically, How does user in a tenant user pool get associated with a policy in an identity pool? There seems to be some hand waving around "Get Access Token (with IAM policies)". How does that work? How do the custom authorizers fit in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roles are associated internally by cognito identity pools. The following code shows that we map this through configuration.

[cognito-user.js:911 - addRoleToIdentity](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/saas-identity-cognito/blob/master/app/source/user-manager/src/cognito-user.js#L911)

```
var cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity(...);

# [ ... ]

RulesConfiguration: {
    Rules: [/* required */
        {
        Claim: 'custom:role', /* required */
        MatchType: 'Equals', /* required */
        RoleARN: identityPoolRoleParams.rolesystem, /* required */
        Value: identityPoolRoleParams.adminRoleName /* required */
        },
        {
        Claim: 'custom:role', /* required */
        MatchType: 'Equals', /* required */
        RoleARN: identityPoolRoleParams.rolesupportOnly, /* required */
        Value: identityPoolRoleParams.userRoleName /* required */
        },
    ]
cognitoidentity.setIdentityPoolRoles(params, function (err, data) {

# [ ... ]
```

This configuration can be represented by the following psuedo-code, where user.'custom:role' is a string.

```
const user = userpool.getuser(...)
if (user.'custom:role' == identityPoolRoleParams.adminRoleName)
    role = identityPoolRoleParams.roleSystem
else if (user.'custom:role' == identityPoolRoleParams.userRoleName) 
    role = identityPoolRoleParams.rolessupportOnly
```